# Fix HP printer software after upgrade (on Arch Linux)

Tags: arch-linux, python, printing, qt, hplip

I am trying to run HP's printer software which was upgraded recently and broke all my printing. I run a constantly upgraded Arch (which is 5.10.14 as of Feb 28, 2021). Apparently they use Qt now so it is some kind of requirement so I spent 2 hours building all this Qt stuff. It seems crazy that HP is requiring linux users to spend hours building obscure packages just so they can print. `lpstat -a` says the printers are ready and working/idle, but nothing can print to them. The cups log says the print failed to a "backend error".

Anyway, hp-setup now just hangs on startup and hp-check gives an error that PyQt4 cannot import QtCore, which is the standard way PyQt users try to verify the version of Qt they are running under. So, apparently there is some kind of version conflict between the two. Here is the relevant section of my pip list:

```
PyOpenGL              3.1.5
pyOpenSSL             20.0.1
pyparsing             2.4.7
PyQt3D                5.15.2
PyQt4-sip             4.19.24
PyQt5                 5.15.2
PyQt5-sip             12.8.1
PyQtChart             5.15.2
PyQtDataVisualization 5.15.2
PyQtPurchasing        5.15.2
PyQtWebEngine         5.15.2
```

So, is the problem that I have PyQt5 on my system and the HP software wants PyQt4? If so, can I have both on the same system? What is the procedure to diagnose this?

```
$ sudo find /usr -name "PyQt*"
/usr/share/qt/qsci/api/python/PyQtDataVisualization.api
/usr/share/qt/qsci/api/python/PyQtPurchasing.api
/usr/share/qt/qsci/api/python/PyQtWebEngine.api
/usr/share/qt/qsci/api/python/PyQt3D.api
/usr/share/qt/qsci/api/python/PyQt5.api
/usr/share/qt/qsci/api/python/PyQtChart.api
/usr/lib/qt/plugins/PyQt5
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQtChart-5.15.3.dist-info
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5_sip-12.8.1-py3.9.egg-info
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQtPurchasing-5.15.3.dist-info
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt4
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt3D-5.15.3.dist-info
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQtDataVisualization-5.15.3.dist-info
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt4_sip-4.19.24.dist-info
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5-5.15.3.dist-info
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQtWebEngine-5.15.3.dist-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4_sip-4.19.24.dist-info
```

The output from HPLIP_DEBUG=1 hp-setup:

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.21.2)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

hp-setup[711208]: debug: param=
hp-setup[711208]: debug: selected_device_name=None
hp-setup[711208]: debug: Using PyQt5
hp-setup[711208]: debug: Sys.argv=['/usr/bin/hp-setup'] printer_name=None param= jd_port=1 device_uri=None remove=False
hp-setup[711208]: debug: Starting GUI Event Loop...
Searching... (bus=net, timeout=5, ttl=4, search=(None) desc=0, method=slp)
error: No devices found on bus: net
error:  HPLIP cannot detect printers in your network.  This may be due to existing firewall settings blocking the required ports.
                When you are in a trusted network environment, you may open the ports for network services like mdns and slp in the firewall. For detailed steps follow the link.
                 http://hplipopensource.com/node/374
```

Comment: Does the version of `hplip` that’s packaged in whatever distribution you’re using work? Is that good enough for the printer you have?

Answer (score 2):

On e.g. Ubuntu 20.10 the `hplip` package will actually run with PyQt5 (`python3-pyqt5`). Same on Arch, the `hplip` package version 3.21.2-1 uses Qt 5. So, no need to install Qt 4.

The used Qt version is actually configured in `/etc/hp/hplip.conf`:

```
[configure]
ui-toolkit=qt5
qt3=no
qt4=no
qt5=yes
```

When I run `hp-check` it does mention that `PyQt4` could not be found, but it does not list it at the end under `Missing Required Dependencies`. If you ask me, this tool is not very trustworthy.

To understand what is going on Python-wise, I would first try to find out where the Qt bindings were installed:

```
$ find /usr -name "PyQt*"
```

You might have multiple Python versions on your system where each has a different directory for its packages. Try calling the tool explicitly with the Python interpreter you think has all the dependencies installed, e.g.:

```
$ export HPLIP_DEBUG=1
$ python3.9 $(where hp-setup)
```

I would expect some hints on what is going wrong in the console output.

One step further could be to run a Python debugger.

If it turns out that the wrong Python interpreter was used, make sure that `python` is pointing to the correct version with:

```
$ python --version
```

However, I don't thing that this is in any way related to PyQt/Qt when looking at the additional console output that you have provided now, especially due to:

```
error: No devices found on bus: net
```

This somehow seems to be related to networking as discovery (SLP) is failing.

Comment: I updated the question with the results of the find command. I run Arch.

Comment: @TylerDurden I've added some more information. If that does not help, maybe you want to remove Qt4/PyQt4 just to be sure.

Comment: When I use python3.9 /usr/sbin/hp-check I get the same error "File /usr/share/hplip/installer/dcheck.py, line 303 in getPyQt4_version from PyQt4 import QtCore, ImportError: cannot import name 'QtCore' from 'PyQt4' (unknown location)

Comment: Well, this guy had the same error even though the config looks correct: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=249343. It turned out to be a different problem after all. Anyway, I recommend you remove PyQt4.

Comment: @TylerDurden please also provide the output of `HPLIP_DEBUG=1 hp-setup`, thanks.

Comment: I added that to the question.

Comment: FWIW, `lpstat -a` on my system lists a printer that's currently switched off as "accepting requests since" [timestamp 6 months into the past]. How is your printer connected? The debug output from `hp-setup` suggests it's using the `net` transport. What does `hp-probe -g -b net` produce? If your printer is connected via USB, what does `hp-probe -g -b usb` produce?

Comment: Also, the HP utilities do not require an X display to run, and I incidentally don't use the GUI myself (I mostly poke the scanner on mine via `scanimage`), so even if you'd prefer to keep using the GUI, it should be very possible to break down "upgrade broke connection to printer" and "upgrade broke GUI" down into two isolated tasks.

Comment: The probe says it cannot find any printers. My printers are on a local ethernet network that has no firewall. Programs that do not use CUPS have no problem accessing and using the printers. For example, I have a Windows laptop on the network and it has no problem printing. Also, I have non-CUPS programs running on my linux boxes that have no problem printing. It is only CUPS/HP that have a problem finding the printers. I have given the static IPs of the printers to the HP discovery and it still cannot "find" the printers.